# Why is this PL/PgSql invalid?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

N00bie PL/PgSql question:

```
create or replace function foo() returns int as $$
declare fff int;
begin
    declare fff int;
    select count(*) into fff from mytable;
    return fff;
end 
$$ language plpgsql
```

output:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 5:   select count(*) into fff from mytable;
                 ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "count(*) into fff from mytable"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `declare` from `begin/end` block:

```
create or replace function foo() returns int as $$
declare fff int;
begin
    --   declare fff int;
    select count(*) into fff from mytable;
    return fff;
end 
$$ language plpgsql
```

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d645e68c216715ccaeacbd5499a246c7)**

> *Ah. Right. So can you not declare a variable inside the BEGIN...END block?*

You declare variables at `declare` part. If you need you could nest blocks:

```
create or replace function foo() returns int as $$
declare fff int;
begin
    declare xxx INT;
    begin
    select count(*) into xxx from mytable;
    return xxx;
    end;
end 
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Ah. Right. So can you not declare a variable inside the `BEGIN...END` block?

Comment: @ShaulBehr You could declare it inside `DECLARE` part.

Comment: Correct. You declare variables in the DECLARE section which precedes the BEGIN.